# Change one keyboard shortcut of VMware Fusion

Tags: virtual-machine, keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-fusion

I'm using Mac, and have installed `VMware Fusion` to get virtual Windows and Linux.

At the moment, by `Ctrl + left arrow` and `Ctrl + right arrow`, I could switch among these 3 systems.

I would like to change this keyboard shortcut. I havn't found this option in `Preferences` of `VMware Fusion`, does anyone know where to set that?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

---

You can disable the CTRL-Right and CTRL-Left arrow buttons using the OSX System Preferences, Keyboard, Mission Control settings.